# Get time duration from multiple datestamps Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, datetime

I have two sets of data that I am trying to manipulate for an expected output using PowerShell. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks for the help in advance

Data 1:

```
StartTime                      Url
2022-01-28T04:44:28.111542Z    Url a
2022-02-02T13:35:15.1040997Z   Url b
2022-02-02T15:33:57.961112Z    Url c
```

Data2:

```
Endtime                         Url
2022-01-28T22:11:39.1086189Z    Url m
2022-02-04T02:49:08.6644804Z    Url d
```

Goal is table below

```
Startime                     Endtime                        Url of Starttime    duration
2022-01-28T04:44:28.111542Z 2022-01-28T22:11:39.1086189Z    Url a   
2022-02-02T15:33:57.961112Z 2022-02-04T02:49:08.6644804Z    Url c
```

Comment: Looks like you want to merge both objects, please provide details on how this output is being generated, is this from a cmdlet  / function ? In addition, please share your coding attempts at solving this problem

Comment: Please elaborate on the `two sets of data`. Are these input CSV files or ?? Please open these up in NotePad and copy the first 3 or 4 lines there. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70987587/edit) your question and paste the lines in there

Comment: Both data are PowerShell objects. Data 1 contains information on the the start of an event and data 2 is the endtime for data 1 events.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data sets are powershell object arrays

You can do:

```
$result = foreach ($item in $data1) {
    $matchingItem = $data2 | Where-Object { $_.Url -eq $item.Url }
    if ($matchingItem) {
        # choose the resolution of the duration. Here I'm using TotalSeconds
        # but you can also opt for TotalDays, TotalHours, TotalMinutes or TotalMilliseconds
        $duration = ([datetime]$matchingItem.EndTime - [datetime]$item.StartTime).TotalSeconds  
        # return a new object with properties combined
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            StartTime            = $item.StartTime
            EndTime              = $matchingItem.EndTime
            Url                  = $item.Url
            'Duration (Seconds)' = $duration
        }
    }
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as new CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\SomePath\durations.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
StartTime                   EndTime                      Url   Duration (Seconds)
---------                   -------                      ---   ------------------
2022-01-28T04:44:28.111542Z 2022-01-28T22:11:39.1086189Z Url a      62830.9970769
2022-02-02T15:33:57.961112Z 2022-02-04T02:49:08.6644804Z Url c     126910.7033684
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my situation, values under Url are never going to match in both Powershell arrays.

Comment: @Lin never match? Then how to know what start time belongs to which end time?

Comment: That is the limbo I am stuck in. So I was wondering if I could use the immediate endtime date right after a Starttime and assume that was the end date. For example, in data 1, I know the event started on 2022-01-28T04:44:28.111542Z and there is an event in the data 2 starting at 2022-01-28T22:11:39.1086189Z. I am assuming that, the event that started in data 2 at 2022-01-28T22:11:39.1086189Z is the endtime for data 1 event starting at 2022-01-28T04:44:28.111542Z.

Comment: @Lin Then... I think you need to rethink the way you construct both input arrays and have them include a property to use for matching the items. Without that, your final output will be nothing more than a series of guesses...

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the data I have and I do not have much control on the output. For the time being I can run with some assumptions/guess. Thanks for the input